# ～ば良い方だった meaning in this sentence from IAIJ

Tags: translation

I'm stuck with this sentence (from *An Integrated Approach To Intermediate Japanese*):

> その頃、私は金がなく、**昼の中華料理で、三十セントと三十五セントの定食のうち**、せいぜい月に一度か二度、**高いのにありつければ良い方だった。**

My attempted (literal) translation is the following:

> At that time I didn't have money (and), **at the chinese food lunch, between a 30 cents or 35 cents fixed price lunch**, at most once or twice a month, it would have been the right choice if I
>   managed to eat expensive things.

I translated the *のうち* as equivalent to *の中* (I think it is correct in this case). What I'm struggling with is the *高いのにありつければ良い方だった* part. My current understanding of that portion is that "*～にありつく*" means "*to get/eat with difficulty*" so "*高いのにありつければ*" means something like "If I manage to eat something expensive..." since I'm treating "高いの" as "高いこと" and ありつければ is the conditional form of the potential form of ありつく. Finally I translated "良い方だった" as "It was the right way/thing to do".

I think I'm missing something since the translation I provided is not very cohesive.
Could you please help me getting a better understanding of these sentence?

Comment: What is the context of this sentence? Is this a dialogue? Or an essay?

Comment: The context is a kind of auto-biography. The guy is talking about an invitation that he received from another student to eat at a chinese restaurant. The previous sentence is this one: "[...] 大学院生がやってきて、「あなたは毎日のように中華料理をたべているそうですが、今晩、 私と一緒に下さいませんか」と誘われた。"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

の in 高いの indeed is a pronoun, but in this case it's not 高いこと "that is expensive; expensiveness" but 高いもの "what is expensive; expensive one". More specifically, 「～のうち（の） [adj.] の」 means "**the** more [adj.] one (of two things)", which is what you see here. Thus 高いのにありつく should be understood "manage to eat the more expensive one (= 35 cent lunch)".

Now, 良い方だ is a kind of idiom that is not comparing anything inside the sentence. It is often used to describe how the situation is wretched, by saying a bad example is still "less bad" than the rest, or an unsatisfactory one all you can wish.

> 彼らはとても兵士と言えたものではなかった。訓練を受けてくれるのはまだ**良い方で**、腹が減ったからと勝手に家に帰る者もいた。弓を取らせても、十回に一回的に当たれば**良い方だった**。
>   *You could by no means call them soldiers. Who willingly went through your training were much praiseworthy when some did go back home without leave because they felt hungry. When you let them shoot arrows, you could at most expect one hit on target every ten.*

Thus, I'd translate せいぜい月に一度か二度、高いのにありつければ良い方だった as:

> I considered myself lucky if I could (manage to) have the expensive one once or twice in a month...

Comment: So essentially I can use ～ば良かった whenever I to express a situation in which even a small quantity represents a big accomplishment.So for instance can I say something like this? 彼は貧しい人で、毎日食べ物を買えれば良い方だった。(He was a poor man and it was an exceptional thing/he was lucky enough if he could buy food every day)

Comment: @Genfu ～ば良かった is another expression "one should have (taken another way)" so don't confuse them. Other than that, your understanding is good in this context and your example is very natural. It doesn't necessarily have to be "small" and "big" in quantity though, rather like how far from your expectation.

Comment: Yeah sorry I made a typo there I was intending  ～ば良い方だった. The weird thing is that I couldn't find anything about this grammatical pattern (neither on the internet nor on the series "A dictionary of ~ Japanese grammar"). This is weird since it doesn't seem like a rare pattern...but anyway thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Genfu I'm just wondering about the same thing. More often than not I find phrases that rather felt as if "advanced" to me on the earlier part of JLPT list, so I thought I might as well be able to get some... It's a quite common expression, though. Maybe they think it too literal to be an idiom?

Answer (score 2):

From [goo辞書: 「のに」](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%9C%89%E3%82%8A%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F/#jn-7553) , one of the definition is

> …時に。…場合に。「地震が来るのに備えておこう」: "*Let's prepare in case the earthquake coming.*"

This time, there are two options of meals for "30 cents or 35 cents". So, 「高いのに」means choosing more expensive one i.e. price of 35 cents.

Also [goo辞書: 「ありつく」](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%9C%89%E3%82%8A%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F/#jn-7553)

「ありつければ」 = 「ありつく」 + 「ければ」: conditional form

> 求めていたものをやっとの思いで手に入れる。

"manage to ~" seems appropriate here since it literally means "A lot of effort have been needed to get what you wanted".

「 "良い方だった"」here means "better off" rather than "the right way/things to do".

It is not talking about 「方法」. Here, 「方」 here means "choose one comparing to others". So, 「良い方」: "choose better one comparing to others"

So, All in all "It was better off if I managed to eat Chinese food which costs 35 cents at most once or twice. "

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything seems clear.

Comment: Just to clarify...so in general can I assume that ～ば良い方だった is equivalent to ～ば良かった?

Comment: @Genfu I think it depends . 「～ば良かった」can be the same if you are mention "making a choice" in the sentence i.e. 「こちらを選べば良かった」sounds similar to「こちらにすれば良い方だった」.